# Do the encoder and decoder architectures of VAE need to be exactly reverse of each other in terms of size of data at each layer?

Tags: autoencoders

For example if we have the encoder architecture as follows:
(number of channels@ h_size x w_size)

1@28x28 |
32@14x14 |
64@7x7 |
128@4x4 |
256@2x2 |
512@1x1

Should the decoder architecture be such that we get the following:

512@1x1 |
256@2x2 |
128@4x4 |
64@7x7 |
32@14x14 |
1@28x28

Or, is it okay if it is like the following:

**512@1x1 |
256@2x2 |
128@4x4 |
64@8x8 |
32@16x16 |
32@32x32 |
1@28x28**

Will having layers as in the bold version cause any problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter.. But you should test it out!

Comment: Thank you for your response!